# Why date_parse does not recognise years in a string

Tags: php, date-parsing

Why `date_parse` does not recognise years in a string?

```
<?php
$string = "Saturday, 23 March, 2013";
print_r(date_parse($string));
?>
```

result,

```
Array
(
    [year] => 
    [month] => 3
    [day] => 23
    [hour] => 20
    [minute] => 13
    [second] => 0
    [fraction] => 0
    [warning_count] => 0
    [warnings] => Array
        (
        )

    [error_count] => 0
    [errors] => Array
        (
        )

    [is_localtime] => 
    [relative] => Array
        (
            [year] => 0
            [month] => 0
            [day] => 0
            [hour] => 0
            [minute] => 0
            [second] => 0
            [weekday] => 6
        )

)
```

Comment: if you KNOW the format of a date you need to parse, then don't try and depend on PHP's own parsing abilities. You WILL get burned at some point. for fixed formats, always use things like date_create_from_format() and eliminate the guesswork.

Comment: thanks. But I am not sure what is the benefits of `date_create_from_format`...

Comment: `$timestamp = date_create_from_format('D, d F, Y')` and you'd end up with a valid timestamp, with the proper year. letting php guess works some of the time, but not ALL of the time.

Comment: now I see the benefit of it. thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the format isn't correct. It does return the correct year, when you do the following.

```
$string = "Saturday, 23 March, 2013";
                             ^ //no comma here, should be just 23 March 2013
```

Everywhere in the [supported formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php), it is seen that all components of the Date-string and the time-string have the same delimiters separating them.

Comment: interestingly, `date('r', strtotime('Saturday, 23 March, 2013'))` does come back with 2013 as expected. must be something odd internally within PHP, because the docs state that date_parse accepts the same formats as strtotime.

Comment: @MarcB It is doing something rather peculiar with the above example you mentioned. It seems to put the 2013 in the `HH:MM` field.

Comment: Actually, @Mark B, it's coming back with 2013 because that's the current year. If you do `print(date('r', strtotime('Saturday, 23 March, 2012')))`, it will print **Sat, 23 Mar 2013 20:12:00 -0600**. It's just a side-effect of the current year being 2013. The 2013 are being parsed as the hour and minute.

Comment: @blake: makes sense. just another reason to avoid strtotime and company like the plague

Answer (score 0):

You might also try strtotime().  It's an amazing function and handles a wide variety of inputs - even relative ones like "3 days ago."